# Shrink Collection View when Navigation Bar added

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uinavigationbar

In my iOS swift app I created UIColletctionViewController with custom UICollectionViewLayout which creates horizontally scrollable parent-child grid layout. Height of this layout is computed so it fits my screen height.

```
override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(
        width: someWidth,
        height: collectionView?.frame.height ?? 0
    )
}
```

When I embed my collection view controller in navigation bar whole collection view gets moved down but `collectionView?.frame.height` remains the same so my content overflows down.

[image]

How do I get height of this reduced usable space without navigation bar?

Comment: Try to invalidate CollectionView Layout when view's frame change.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found very easy solution that works for me. I unchecked "Under Top Bars" option in Attributes inspector of my collection view controller.

[image: UICollectionViewController]

Answer (score 1):

If your view controller sets `edgesForExtendedLayout` to `.all` or `.top` and `automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true` (which looks like is the case) then your collectionView's `contentInset` gets adjusted to compensate for the navigation bar's height, so check for that inset.

Assuming your collectionView extends to top (starts behind nav bar) get the visible height:

```
let visibleHeight = collectionView.frame.height - collectionView.contentInset.top
```

In your case you can do:

```
override var collectionViewContentSize: CGSize {
    return CGSize(
        width: someWidth,
        height: collectionView.frame.height - collectionView.contentInset.top
    )
}
```

Another option is to set `edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge(rawValue: UInt(0))` then your view controller's view will not extend to either edge and will originate below the navigation bar, thus your collection view's frame will be in the visible bounds and you can use the `collectionViewContentSize` like it is in your example.

Comment: My `collectionView.contentInset.top` is set to zero so that doesn't work. But this second solution with setting `edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdge(rawValue: UInt(0))` works. Thanks!

Comment: Great. Then you can check it as answered :)

Comment: @Peracek btw, for the other solution check `collectionView.contentInset.top` in `viewWillAppear` or `viewWillLayoutSubviews`, because the insets are not adjusted yet in `viewDidLoad`.